# c:forEach calls its getter for each p:remoteCommand

Tags: jsf, el, getter

I do have an JEE application with JSF. As soon as I do use the `c:forEach` element, then the backend call for detecting the items is called with each `p:remoteCommand`, talking to the backend, even if no update is done at all.

I do not have any idea why this is done! Can anybody help me with a solution or a workaround?

In Detail, I use Wildfly (e. g. version 26.0.1, but also seen with e. g. version 28) and PrimeFaces (version 11, also seen with other versions).
Switching from `c:forEach` to e. g. `ui:repeat` is not so simple, because in my real world usage I call an `ui:include` for each of the iterating elements for getting a very flexible UI. So far, this did only work with `c:forEach`.

But let's take a closer look to a minimal code example:

If I do have an XHTML page like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:head>
        <title>Playground: c:forEach and p:remoteCommand</title>
    </h:head>

    <p:remoteCommand name="doSomethingRemote" actionListener="#{controllerBean.doSomething()}" process="@this" />

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
        
            <c:forEach items="#{controllerBean.elementList}" var="element">
                <p:outputLabel value="Element: #{element}"/><br/>
            </c:forEach>
            
            <p:commandButton value="call Remote Command" onsuccess="doSomethingRemote();" process="@none" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

and a Java backend like:

```
@Named
public class ControllerBean {

    private static final Logger LOG=Logger.getLogger(ControllerBean.class);

    private List<String> elementList=new ArrayList<>();

    public ControllerBean() {
        elementList.add("First");
        elementList.add("Second");
        elementList.add("Third");
    }

    public List<String> getElementList() {
        LOG.info("getElementList() is called");
        return elementList;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        LOG.info("doSomething() is called");
    }
}
```

Each time I press the button, calling the remote command, the method `getElementList()` is called three times, then one time `doSomething()` and then a fourth call of `getElementList()`.

**Edit(1):** I know that getter can be called multiple times, but why is any getter called if I just call a remote comand and do not need to render or update anything of my page? And why is it only done for c:forEach?
If I just replace the whole c:forEach with e. g.

```
<p:outputLabel value="Element: #{controllerBean.elementList.get(0)}"/>
```

I do not have this behaviour at all!

Comment: I know that a getter is not only called once but multiple times during rendering a page. But my question is, why is anything rendered when I just call a remote command? I do not have any update and no need for a render at all!